Twilio Voice JavaScript SDK Error - 31206: Rate exceeded authorized limit details
There is limited documentation on Error: 31206 in the Twilio docs (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/31206). Was wondering if anyone can help go into more detail on what could trigger this error?
Could say, too many devices connected at once through device.connect cause this? It is just a little unclear what "rate" is being exceeded.
I want to utilize the Voice JavaScript SDK to handle multiple calls going off at the same time. I'm wondering what limits I should consider in order to not reach a rate limit while integrating the SDK into my application.

Looking at this documentation we can see that 312XXX errors are related to authorization errors. Can you check if your application is successfully connected to Twilio Voice SDK?
